# Unlock character with unlock button (multi-childe object) in Unity 3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hi Stackoverflow community, wish you all the best,

please, help me with advice on how to implement unlock system for characters. I have one Player object on the game scene with 10+ child objects = character mesh skins. So I doing disabling all child objects and enabled only one, chosen one. And I implement choosing skin by clicking left/right button and when the user clicks "play" btn, he can play with chosen skin.

But I want to add "unlock" btn with buying functional (with PlayerPrefs).
I stuck with that, please, help if I am not asking some stupid or common things.

I am learning C# and Unity only for around 3 months, so please, if it is possible, try to keep your advice as simple as possible.
Thank you in advance!

Here is how I made choose character script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class CharacterSelect : Singleton<CharacterSelect>
{
    GameObject[] characters;
    int index;
    //TODO public int cost;

    public GameObject leftBtn, rightBtn;
    public Button play;

    void Start()
    {
        characters = new GameObject[transform.childCount - 3];  //-3 because I am using root objects
                                                                //for animation as a child of the obj
                                                                //with two other obj (shield boost and trail)

        for (int i = 0; i < transform.childCount; i++)
        {
            characters[i] = transform.GetChild(i).gameObject;
        }

        foreach (GameObject go in characters)
        {
            go.SetActive(false);
        }

        if (characters[0])
        {
            characters[0].SetActive(true);
        }
    }

    public void SelectLeft()
    {
        characters[index].SetActive(false);
        index--;
        if (index < 0)
        {
            index = characters.Length - 1;

        }
        characters[index].SetActive(true);
    }

    public void SelectRight()
    {
        characters[index].SetActive(false);
        index++;
        if (index == characters.Length)
        {
            index = 0;
        }
        characters[index].SetActive(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should probably break down your problem. What do you actually need to do to implement your feature. Detecting whether a skin is already unlocked or not. Disabling the play button if it is and enabling if it isn't. For that you can probably use as you said PlayerPrefs be aware tough these can be changed easily by a user because it is only a single text file on the users computer that he has complete access too.

Comment: It depends on how you would like to do it, but perhaps saving a boolean as a integer could work where the name of the PlayerPrefs is the GameObject Name you want to unlock / lock.

Comment: You would need to then simply call ```PlayerPrefs.SetInt(gameObject.name, (int)true)``` for the object you are currently on if he clicks an Unlock button and has enough points.

Comment: If you did that the only thing you need to do is loop through all game objects that are skins get their respective names with `gameObject.name` and depending on the value in the PlayerPrefs unlock or lock the skin `PlayerPrefs.GetInt(gameObject.name, (int)false);` (The second parameter of `PlayerPrefs.GetInt` is the default value if you haven't saved one yet.

Comment: @IndieGameDev thank you a lot, you describe it as a guru and now I understand how I can solve that situation! One more time - THANK YOU!! I think from very beginning I should to choose another approach for selecting characters to simplify unlocking process. Each time each case teaches us some new.